# Python multidimensional array not returning inside if

Tags: python, list

I have this code that is progressively generating a larger multidimensional array recursively.

```
def lex(stop,n = 2,array = [[0,0],[1,-1]]):
    if n == 2:
        if stop == 2:
            return array
        else:
            return lex(stop,n+1,array)

    else:
        newArray = []
        for x in range(n):
            for y in range(len(array)):
                newArray.append(array[y][:])

        for x in range(len(newArray)):
            pos = x // factorial(n-1)
            newArray[x].insert(pos,-pos)
            for y in range(pos):
                if y < x: newArray[x][y] += 1

        if n == stop:
            print(newArray)
            return newArray
        else:
            lex(stop,n+1,newArray)
```

The strange part is at the end in the `if n == stop` block. `print(newArray` prints the correct array but the `return` statement doesn't seem to work. Any attempt at printing the result just shows `None`.

Is there something functionally wrong with how I'm returning the array?

Comment: These are Python `list` objects (Python's `array` module is a different type).

Comment: `lex(stop,n+1,newArray)` should be returned.

Comment: Lists eh? Alright, thanks. I have a very heavy JavaScript background so I keep calling dictionaries 'objects' too.

Comment: [array — Efficient arrays of numeric values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return newArray` is working fine; you forgot a return statement for the recursive call in the `else` branch:

```
if n == stop:
    print(newArray)
    return newArray
else:
    # don't ignore this recursive call
    return lex(stop,n+1,newArray)
```

You want to *avoid* using a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-which-scope-is-the-mutable-default-argument-in) to your function; use a sentinel like `None` instead:

```
def lex(stop, n=2, array=None):
    if array is None:
        array = [[0, 0], [1, -1]]
```

Cleaning up the code a little more:

```
def lex(stop, n=2, array=None):
    if array is None:
        array = [[0, 0], [1, -1]]

    if n == 2:
        return array if stop == 2 else lex(stop, n + 1, array)

    new = [nested[:] for _ in range(n) for nested in array]

    for x, nested in enumerate(new):
        pos = x // factorial(n - 1)
        nested.insert(pos, -pos)
        for y in range(pos):
            nested[y] += 1

    return new if n == stop else lex(stop, n + 1, new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and recommendation about the default arguments.

Comment: Wow, that new code just blew my mind. I'm really quite new to Python and many of these cool ways of doing things aren't available in JS.